# decrypt AES key with RSA private key

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt AES key with RSA private key.

here is the exception:

> [10/2/18 15:36:07:841 EEST] 00000082 SystemErr     R    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
>       [10/2/18 15:36:07:841 EEST] 00000082 SystemErr     R    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSACipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
>       [10/2/18 15:36:07:841 EEST] 00000082 SystemErr     R    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
>       [10/2/18 15:36:07:841 EEST] 00000082 SystemErr     R    at com.cms.g2g.service.EncryptionService.decryptKey(EncryptionService.java:134)

and here is my code:

```
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

public static SecretKeySpec decryptKey (String decAESAsString, PrivateKey  privateKey) 
         throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    Cipher cipher = null;

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

    try {
        byte [] data = Base64.decode(decAESAsString);
        SecretKeySpec aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(cipher.doFinal(data), "AES");
        return aeskeySpec ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;  
}
```

Comment: ??? RSA and AES are completely different algorithms they even belong to different cryptographic families. Why do you think you can decrypt an AES encrypted thing using an RSA private key?

Comment: I think OP is trying to decrypt an AES **key** using RSA (this is a fairly standard use of RSA algorithm). The AES key would be used to encrypt/decrypt the actual plaintext.

Comment: Where is the encrypt code?

Comment: The code looks ok on the first sight, the exception may be result of invalid resulting padding. IMHO you either may be using different key or the padding used is different.